# How test Select2(Multi-select) in protractor?

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I have a Select2(Multi-select),I want to type `admin` and select it.

this my HTML code :

```
<select class="js-select2" multiple="multiple">
    <option> admin </option>
    <option> John Doe </option>
</select>
```

this is my test code :

```
describe('when select admin and press save button', function () {
        beforeAll(function () {
            browser.get('http://example');
            element(by.css("*[id='technician'] + span.select2")).click();
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.css(".select2-search__field")).sendKeys('admin');
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.css('.select2-results__options li:nth-of-type(1)')).click();
            element(by.buttonText('save')).click();
        });

        it('You must see a successful message', function () {
            expect(element(by.css(".alert")).getText()).toContain('Settings saved successfully');
        });
    });
```

When I execute the code, Protractor gives this message :

> Failed: element not interactable

Where did i make mistakes ? and What should i do ?

Comment: Can you add html code so it can be reproduced?

Comment: @SilvanBregy yes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select2` is a jQuery plugin, which implement dropdown with css & javascript, it's not native dropdown which implement purely by `select`.

For such CSS dropdown, the visible option does not comes from `select` and the `select` is invisible or visible but with very small size (like 1 * 1 size) prevent user to operate it.

Below code example test on the demo from [Select2 site](https://select2.org/selections)

```
describe('handsontable', function(){

    it('input text into cell', function(){

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('https://select2.org/selections');
        browser.sleep(3000);

        // click to make the input box and options display out
        element(by.css('select.js-example-basic-multiple-limit + span' +
                       ' .select2-selection--multiple')).click();


        browse.sleep(1000);
        element(by.css("select.js-example-basic-multiple-limit + span input"))
           .sendKeys('Hawaii');

        element(by.xpath("//li[@role='treeitem'][text()='Hawaii']")).click();        

        browser.sleep(3000);
    });

})
```